# Project server Remote Event Handler

Tags: sharepoint-online, project-server, provider-hosted-app, remote-event-receiver, autohosted

So I've added a .svc file that implements `IProjectEventReceiverRemote` to my provider/auto hosted SharePoint app. And I've registered this following this example http://www.ro.umt.com/blog/2013/08/01/project-server-2013-remote-event-handlers/ (slightly modified, since I'm using an MVC app). Registering and unregistering the event handler works fine.

However, when trying to debug this locally using Windows Azure Service bus I get the following output in my SharePoint tools output window

```
Cannot register ProjectPublished.svc on Windows Azure Service Bus: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
One or more services were unregistered from the Windows Azure Service Bus.
```

When trying to deploy the app online without debugging, the event handlers just never get hit. When I try to visit the .svc in my browser I'm getting:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually fixed it by copying the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime` dll from an on premises SharePoint farm and adding a reference to it. Then it requires `Microsoft.Office.Project.Schema` which is missing from the current version of the SDK. I found this dll in an old RTM version of the SDK here: http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-components-postattachments/00-10-40-35-79/REDIST.zip